# Passing parameter to async class such that param[0] and params[1] contain different values

Tags: java, android

I am developing an Android app of weather. I am passing the postal code as input to an async task class. But I want to pass country code along with it.

```
     @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_refresh) {
        FetchWeatherTask weatherTask = new FetchWeatherTask();
        weatherTask.execute("110087"); //THE ARGUMENT I PAASED IS POSTAL CODE

        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

I want to pass country code (e.g. `IN`) also, so that when I build my uri it has postalcode, `IN`

Example:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&APPID=74250c25b0f8a52f176e6d6e3717e285
```

If I include the country code, it should be:

```
http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=94043,IN&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&APPID=74250c25b0f8a52f176e6d6e3717e285
```

Code:

```
String format = "json";
String units = "metric";
int numDays = 7;

try {
    // Construct the URL for the OpenWeatherMap query
    // Possible parameters are avaiable at OWM's forecast API page, at
    // http://openweathermap.org/API#forecast
    final String FORECAST_BASE_URL =
                    "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?";
    final String QUERY_PARAM = "q";
    final String FORMAT_PARAM = "mode";
    final String UNITS_PARAM = "units";
    final String DAYS_PARAM = "cnt";
    final String APPID_PARAM = "APPID";

    Uri builtUri = Uri.parse(FORECAST_BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                    .appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])
                    .appendQueryParameter(FORMAT_PARAM, format)
                    .appendQueryParameter(UNITS_PARAM, units)
                    .appendQueryParameter(DAYS_PARAM, Integer.toString(numDays))
                    .appendQueryParameter(APPID_PARAM, BuildConfig.OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY)
                    .build();

    URL url = new URL(builtUri.toString());

    Log.v(LOG_TAG, "Built URI " + builtUri.toString());
```

The easy solution is to pass :

```
weatherTask.execute("110087IN");
```

but I want to append query at uri build and also i want to pass 2 entities to the class, such that like params[0] is "110087" so params[1] should be "IN".

I hope you understand the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `AsyncTask` like this

```
private class FetchWeatherTask extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void doInBackground(Object... params) {

        String postalCode = (String) params[0];
        String countryCode = (String) params[1];
        // if you also want to pass third value in type int it should be like
        //int thirdValue = (Integer) params[3]
    }
    ...
}
```

Then you can pass multiple value with different type to your `AsyncTask`

```
weatherTask.execute("110087", "IN")
```

Answer (score 3):

The `execute()` method of the `AsyncTask` can accept multiple arguments. If you need to pass more arguments, you just do it like this:

```
weatherTask.execute("110087", "IN")
```

Then `params[0]` is `"110087"`, `params[1]` is `"IN"`

Comment: But how will i use params[1] in my uri builder it gives an error if i use
.appendQueryParameter(QUERY_PARAM, params[0])